# Separating date and time, matlab

Tags: matlab

I have vector of string

> DateTime=[' 29.11.2012 19:37; ' 28.11.2012 19:38'; ....];

How can I separete it into yeras,  months,days,  hours, minutes.

I tried **datevec** but i am getting false results.

regards,

Comment: What do you mean you are getting false results ?  Show us your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything seems to work fine for me. Note that you'll have to supply the dates as a cell array of strings, and that you have to specify the proper format for `datevec`:

```
DateTime={' 29.11.2012 19:37'; ' 28.11.2012 19:38'};
datevec(DateTime,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM')
ans =
        2012          11          29          19          37           0
        2012          11          28          19          38           0
```